# How to align a UIBarButtonItem on toolBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added a tool bar and I am adding a button to that toolbar. That button is automatically aligned to left irrespective to the frame that i set to that button. I want that button to be center of the tool bar. How to make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a flexible space to your tabbar to the left (and right) of your button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                            target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: I have a customized button. that button i want to add to uibarbuttonItem... then how to use system item?

Answer (score 0):

along with the button, add a flexible space item on the right and on the left sides of the button